# C++: getline is beings skipped for user input

Tags: c++, user-input

The first call for getline() is being skipped but the second call is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
string animal, q;
cout << "Darn, I lost. What was is?";

getline(cin, animal);//this is being skipped
cout << "Enter a question that is true for a(n) " << animal << " and false for a(n) " << question->value << ": ";
getline(cin, q);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: try `getline(cin >> std::ws, animal);` and comment with the result.

Comment: Both `getline` works in my machine! (gcc compiler)

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because that code you show will not, by itself, exhibit the problems you're having.

Comment: Thanks for commenting you guys, but I found out my problem. I posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you had some other input before this.Put a getchar() before getline to consume buffer stored characters.

```
 getchar();
 getline(cin, animal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is like `hello\n how are you?`
and you use `cin` to read hello and `getline` to read `how are you?` it won't work. because the getline will read `\n` and not the the following line to fix this. you can use `cin.ignore()` to ignore `\n` and then use `getline` to read the following line.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, it was being somewhere else in my code I used the standard "`cin`" rather than `getline()`, and I guess there was still something in the buffer, like @Sourav Kanta said. I guess I should either use one or the other next time, and not both.

Comment: Also next time, please try searching for a solution as this particular question is *extremely* common on SO.